# Image div popup some time working and sometime not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hey I am trying to create a image Popup section. there I am got a unique problem, first i load my website after that when I hover on div then some image scaling and some image is not scaling, Not scaling image is also not working on click.

HTML

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="image"><img src="asset/images1.jpg" alt="1"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="asset/images2.jpg" alt="2"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="asset/images3.jpg" alt="3"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="asset/images4.jpg" alt="4"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="asset/images5.jpg" alt="5"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="asset/images6.jpg" alt="6"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="asset/images7.jpg" alt="7"></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="asset/images8.jpg" alt="8"></div>
    </main>
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="cross">X</div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="overlay_img">

    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgb(75,151,245);
    background: linear-gradient(132deg, rgba(75,151,245,1) 8%, rgba(229,132,232,1) 77%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
main{
    width: 100%;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
}
main .image{
    width: 300px;
    height: 290px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
main .image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
main .image img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
#overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.821);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: none;
    transition: all 5s ease-in;
}
.overlay_img{
    width: 65%;
    height: 70%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 55%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    overflow: hidden;
} 
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
    .overlay_img{
        width: 500px;
        height: 55%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:524px) {
    .overlay_img{
        width: 300px;
        height: 40%;
    }
}
@keyframes grow {
    0%,100%{
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}
.overlay_img img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    animation: grow 2s ease;
}
#cross{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    top: 12%;
    left: 48%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```js
let displayImage = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
let image = document.createElement('img');
let appendImage = document.querySelector('.overlay_img');
let overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');
let cross = document.querySelector('#cross');


const displayClose = ()=>{
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
    appendImage.style.display = 'none';
    // enableScroll();
}

for (let i = 0; i < displayImage.length; i++) {
  displayImage[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    overlay.style.display = 'block';
    appendImage.style.display = 'block';
    image.src = `asset/images${i+1}.jpg`;
    if (e.target.alt == i+1) {
        appendImage.appendChild(image);
        // disableScroll();
    }
  });
}

addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
        if(e.key === 'Escape'){
            if (overlay.style.display == 'block') {
                displayClose();
            }
        }
    })

const disableScroll = ()=>{
    scrollTop = window.pageYoffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    scrollLeft = window.pageXoffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;

    window.onscroll = function(){
        window.scrollTo(screenLeft,scrollTop);
    };
}
const enableScroll = ()=> {
    window.onscroll = function() {};
}
overlay.addEventListener('click',displayClose);
```

Please Check My all code and please comment thank you

Comment: Which part of this is supposed to have anything to do with the `facebook-javascript-sdk`?